# Is there a meaning ascribed to where you put the pointer indicator "*" in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c

Here is an embarrassingly simple question that I have not been able to find an answer to as I delve into Objective C:

Is there a meaning ascribed to where you put the pointer indicator '*' when declaring or assiging a variable?

I have seen variables defined in different ways:

```
 NSString  *BLANK_SPACE = @" ";
 NSString const *BLANK_SPACE = @" ";
 NSString * const BLANK_SPACE = @" ";
```

Now I know the meaning of the CONST modifier, but I put it there only because when I see the asterisk separated by a space, it is usually before a CONST modifier.

Can someone explain the rationale about where to put the * when declaring/assigning a variable? What is the difference?

Comment: Dont know the answer but it's a very good question :). If newton had thought asking question suach as why apple fall? We would be unaware of gravity ;)

Comment: Good question. I think the 'C' parts of obj-c are the hardest part for beginners.

Comment: I'll note that, for a standard pointer declaration such as `NSString * myString;` all of the blanks are optional -- could be `NSString *myString;`, `NSString* myString;`, or `NSString*myString;`.  Probably `NSString *myString;` is the most common (and what xCode tends to auto-generate), but I personally prefer `NSString* myString;`, since I associate the "pointerness" of the declaration with the type, not the variable.  However, one does need to be careful when declaring multiple variables together (`NSString* myString1, * myString2;`), or, better, avoid multiple declarations on the same line.

Comment: Re `const`, the style I see most often (and the one I prefer) is to place it to the left of the type (first thing on the line) when declaring a pointer to a constant value (which is the most common use of `const` ).  This is hard to confuse.  Then, if the `const` appears anywhere else that's a signals to say to yourself "Whoa! Think about this."

Comment: @Daniel - If I am not mistaken, wouldn't putting the CONST first, to the left of the type, be declaring a const string as opposed to a const pointer? based on the comments below, I would think that is not what you really want most of the time in objective-c.

Comment: Yes, const to the left makes whatever's pointed to const.   But this is the most common use -- `const char*` and the like.  `const` has very little use in Objective C, outside of "C-isms" such as `const char*`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`const` is a postfix operator that refers to the thing to its left, as opposed to the right.  If the `const` comes first then it applies to the first thing after it.  `const NSString *foo` (as well as `NSString const *foo`) means that it's a non-const pointer to a const NSString - the pointer value can be reassigned, but the data being pointed to is immutable. `NSString * const foo` means that it's a const pointer to a non-const NSString - the data being pointed to can change but the location the pointer refers to cannot.

Spacing between the `*` and other parts of the line are just a matter of style and clarity.

Comment: Please also refer to @Caleb's answer about stylistically which placement of the * is more appropriate. This is really rooted in C and some of the ambiguity in that language, but the style prescribed by Caleb really makes it clear what the * applies to. I went through this song and dance with C/C++ many years ago, and while it doesn't make a shred of difference linguistically, it makes a world of difference when you're looking back through old and forgotten code!

Comment: Here is another thread that also talks about the confusing distinction between const pointers or const objects: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/593498/problem-with-declare-a-global-variable-in-objective-c

Comment: While @Caleb's answer is correct, it doesn't answer the question. The placement of `const` does indeed make a difference. It determines whether the data is constant or whether the pointer itself is constant.

Answer (score 2):

The trick is to read the declarations from right to left. So:

```
NSString  *BLANK_SPACE
```

Right to left... BLANK_SPACE is a pointer to an NSString.

```
NSString const *BLANK_SPACE
```

Right to left... BLANK_SPACE is a pointer to a const NSString.

```
NSString * const BLANK_SPACE
```

Right to left... BLANK_SPACE is a const pointer to an NSString.

Finally,

```
NSString const * const BLANK_SPACE
```

Right to left... BLANK_SPACE is a const pointer to a const NSString.

Comment: THanks - this is a great explanation. I see now that what adds to the confusion for me is this concept: NSString const *BLANK_SPACE. What does a constant string mean? The link I posted above (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/593498/problem-with-declare-a-global-variable-in-objective-c/3812205#3812205) suggests this is meaningless. Is there a reason to make a constant string?

Comment: In Obj-C its fair to say that the NSString const* syntax makes little sense, since NSStrings are immutable and hence already const. That syntax makes sense for non Obj-C class types (e.g. int, char), and also makes sense in C++ where the notion of const methods exists. There, only const methods can be called on const objects. Obj-C has nothing like that; it relies on the simpler idea of objects that can't be changed (like NSString)!

Answer (score 1):

The position of the * relative to the variable name doesn't matter to the compiler. Some prefer to put the * with the variable, though, because it avoids possible confusion when declaring multiple variables:

```
char* a, b;  // a is char* and b is char, but both look like char*
char *a, b;  // looks a little more like the truth: a is char*, b is char
```

However you *always* refer to objects in Objective-C via pointers, so you'd never do something like the first line below:

```
NSString *a, b;  // WRONG: a is a pointer to an NSString object, b is just wrong.
NSString *a, *b; // OK: both a and b are pointers to NSString objects
```

The position of `const`, on the other hand, does make a difference:

```
int * const a; // a points to an int, and a can't be modified to point to some other int
int const * a; // a points to an int, and that int can't be changed
```

Now, `const` doesn't make a lot of sense with respect to objects. For one thing, NSString represents an immutable string, so declaring one `const` doesn't add much. For another, one generally modifies an object in Objective-C by sending a message, not by changing the object's ivars directly, and I don't believe the compiler will prevent changes made via messages. Therefore, a `const` pointer makes sense, a pointer to a `const` object, not so much:

```
NSString * const BLANK_SPACE = @" "; // makes sense; pointer BLANK_SPACE can't change
NSString const * BLANK_SPACE = @" "; // not useful
```

Comment: `NSString const *` and `NSString * const` are not the same thing.

Comment: @lemnar, you're right of course -- I was thinking about the position of the * relative to the variable name and not the const.

Comment: @Caleb, my apologies for, in my confusion, inadvertently asking two questions at once.

Comment: @JohnRock, no worries -- I've updated my answer to be more complete, and a couple of downvotes are no big deal.